# Ckeditor getData of all instance which id begin by "content_"

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor, push

I want to getData() of all CKEditor instances in my page which their id begin by "desccription_" to put these data in a array but it doesn't work, this is my code:

```
var tab_desc = new Array();
$('#bloc_etapes fieldset').each(function(index)
{       
    var desc_dyn = CKEDITOR.instances[id^="description_"].getData();
    //var desc_dyn = $('#desc_etape'+(index+1)).val();  -------------------------ok with textarea only(without replacing them by CKE)
    tab_desc.push(desc_dyn);
});
```

if somebody have the solution i will be gratefull to him!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tab_desc = [];
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    if (i.indexOf('description_') == 0) {
        tab_desc.push(CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData());
    }
}
```

UPDATE: To use textareas without id/name, instantiate them using themselves as DOM elements like this:

```
$('textarea').each(function() {
    CKEDITOR.replace(this);
});
```

Then, each instance will be named editor1, editor2 and so on.

UPDATE2: To get data from CKEditor instances whose original textareas have a class named 'my_custom_class', use this:

```
for (var i in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    if (CKEDITOR.instances[i].element.$.classList.contains('my_custom_class')) {
        console.log(CKEDITOR.instances[i].getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! ;) it works for me but i have another probleme i guess you cannot get data of two CKE with the same name/id so i can't be able to get data of all my instance cause i have CKE with the same name

Comment: No, you can't. If you have multiple instances with duplicate id/name, only the last instance will be available for interaction, because `CKEditor.instances` will contain only one instance.

Comment: ok thanks but it is possible to replace textarea with ckeditor without an id on the textarea?

Comment: or change the name of my first instance?

Comment: If you have different id, the names don't matter, it can be the same. If you don't use id at all, you need to have different names then.

Comment: Thanks but the idea is to replace textarea whithout name or id ans let ckeditor take the name that it wants.. my problem is that i introduction textarea between former textarea and this new textarea will be replace with cke but will Also take the name/id of the step that it replace :/ so this former textarea will be actualised from n to n+1 and the new will become the n step i dont know if im clear..

Comment: Thanks u a lot for your information :) i Will search tomorrow a what to turn around this caracteristics on the instanciation

Comment: You can have textareas without name and ckeditor instances will be automatically named editor1, editor2 and so on. But you can not set the the instance name yourself. CKEditor does that, from textarea id or textarea name or automatically.

Comment: yes but i dont find how to replace textarea without id/name in parameters.What is the function ?

Comment: Thanks man :) there is still a problem i want to getdata of all ckeditor instances in my page but in the order af apperance in my page not of instanciation to put them in an array in order of apparition in the page. So i ask myself if it is possible to getData of all ckeditor with a certain class ?

Comment: I updated my answer again. If you like it, please kindly accept it as answer by clicking the checkmark :-)

Comment: thanks :) i tried it works to get all the data and push it in an array but i have stil my problem the "for" get all the ckeditor instances by order of instaciation and no by order of apperance on the document...